# how to prevent yammer to open new tab for authentication

Tags: yammer

I am using yammer REST API to get group data in sharepoint from yammer, it is opening a new tab for authentication. Is there any way to prevent this new tab?

I tried to open yammer in a hidden iframe, which gives me error -  "Refused to display  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the JS SDK to make REST API calls.  It needs a way to authenticate those calls so if it doesn't have an OAuth token to use from another source, it prompts you to login.  Take a look at this blog post that describes how to preauthorize the JS SDK so you can start making API calls scoped to the user loading the page without requiring any interaction from the user.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askyammer/2016/11/04/preauthorizing-the-yammer-js-sdk/